# Ruby: grammar name for [number] after subclass of one class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Rails by example. I see in migration folder here is one sample code:

```
class RemoveOrderListNumberAndStateFromOrderLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    remove_column :order_lists, :order_list_number
    remove_column :order_lists, :state
  end

  def down
    add_column :order_lists, :order_list_number, :string
    add_column :order_lists, :state, :integer
  end
end
```

The thing I don't know is at this line:

```
class RemoveOrderListNumberAndStateFromOrderLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
```

I know this command means: create a class, that is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Migration` and also 5.0 is rails version of project. Thing that I don't know is: which ruby grammar name that allow you declare `[number]` after class in above case. I think the only way is an array, but not likely true in this case.

thanks

Comment: If you're satisfied with one of the answers, please accept one by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag You marked my post is duplicated with an older post :D Please think carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby language comes with a lot of what is called "syntactic sugar," which allows you to express the same ideas in different ways. The purpose of sugar is to allow the programmer to find a way to express the idea in a way that makes the most sense to that individual.

In your case, the square brackets are just another way to call a method with arguments -- there's no functional difference. `proc[]` is another way to say `proc.call()`, so the brackets are just hiding the `call`. Usually, you only see these brackets in conjunction with lambdas. There's no specific "grammar name" that goes with this type of notation -- it's just notation.

Specifically, this is a class method being called on `ActiveRecord::Migration` that tells the class what migration version is being used. Note: if you have the release version of Rails, you shouldn't need that notation -- it should have been removed after the beta finished.

You can see where and how `ActiveRecord::Migration` uses that class method in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0e835960c78f81bf0a78463d4bee2915a9b75de3/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L526)

```
    def self.[](version)
      version = version.to_s
      name = "V#{version.tr('.', '_')}"
      unless Compatibility.const_defined?(name)
        versions = Compatibility.constants.grep(/\AV[0-9_]+\z/).map { |s| s.to_s.delete('V').tr('_', '.').inspect }
        raise "Unknown migration version #{version.inspect}; expected one of #{versions.sort.join(', ')}"
      end
      Compatibility.const_get(name)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L526), you'd see that this is used to find the Compatibility version of `ActiveRecord::Migration`, in your case, this would have returned the class `ActiveRecord::Migration::Current` so your migration would be a subclass of that class.

Currently, I think there are only 2 versions available: v4.2 and v5.0.