# Ruby 2.4 documentation for this bracket syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have not used Ruby in quite sometime and ran into some unfamiliar syntax:

```
class AddQuantityToLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

The `[5.1]` seems to be forcing a particular ActiveRecord::Migration version? What is this syntax called and where can the documentation for it be found?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543894/ruby-grammar-name-for-number-after-subclass-of-one-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a familiar syntax, but it's unfamiliar in this location, that's all. The base class specifier is allowed to be an expression, which can include method calls.

Here's a way of re-creating that situation:

```
class CrazyProxyClass
  def [](v)
     Class.new
  end
end

CrazyMethod = CrazyProxyClass.new

class CrazyDerived < CrazyMethod[1.2]
end

CrazyDerived.new
# => CrazyDerived
```

You can also get even more adventurous:

```
class NormalBase
end

class DebugBase < NormalBase
end

class Example < (ENV['DEBUG'] ? DebugBase : NormalBase)
end
```

The only limit is your imagination and tools like Rubocop that will tell you it's *probably a bad idea* to get this nuts. The only real obligation is that whatever that expression returns is a Class or you'll get a "superclass must be a Class" exception.